# Binding IPagedList with checkbox as List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So.. i have a class that has has a `List`.
 I pass it to the view like the code below:

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Roles="user")]
[CustomChecker]
public ActionResult Index(int? page, int id=0)
{
    EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();
    student st = emp.students.Single(x=>x.id ==id);

    @ViewBag.id = st.id;

    return View(st.subjSel.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 4));
}
```

And then the View will receive it like this:

```
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model PagedList<MvcApplication6.Models.subject>
<div style="font-family:Arial">
    <fieldset>
        <legend><h3>Open Classes</h3></legend>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Enrollment"))
        {
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@ViewBag.id" />
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].subj)</th>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].days)</th>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].cstart)</th>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].cend)</th>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].professor)</th>
                    <th>@Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].units)</th>
                    <th>@Html.CheckBox("test") Select all</th>
                </tr>
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].id)
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].subj)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].subj)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].days)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].days)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].cstart)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].cstart)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].cend)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].cend)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].professor)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].professor)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].units)
                            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].units)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m[i].isSelected)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
            <table>
                <tr><td align="center" width="500px"></td></tr>
                 <tr>
                    <td align="center" width="500px">
                        <input type="submit" value="submit" /> | <input type="button" value="clear" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
        }
    </fieldset>
</div>
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", "Enrollment", new { page, id = Request.QueryString["id"] }))
```

My problem is that it will be rendered like this `[0].subj` and that won't allow me to bind because it should be something like `name[0].subj`.

I've been experimenting and trying new methods, are there any ways for me to bind them properly? i want to use `Html Helpers` and as much as possible, i don't want to re-implement a custom one just for this part.

This is the function where they are supposed to be bound. This class has a `List` of students (the one that i converted to IPagedList)

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles="user")]
public ActionResult Test(student st)
```

And this is how my `View` looks like. I am using `CheckBoxFor` for selections.
[image]

**Extra question:**
How come my navigation looks so ugly?

Comment: It is and should be `[0].subj` (not `name[0].subj`) because you model is `PagedList<subject>` not `student`, which means you POST method needs to be `IEnumerable<subject>` not `student`. Alternatively if you want `student` in the POST method, the model in the view needs to be `student`.

Comment: But you not generating any controls for `student` anyway (except for the `id` property) so that can easily be added as a route value so you get it in the POST method

Comment: So if it's `[0].subj` then it should be `IEnumerable<subject>` ?

Comment: Yes (and the answer below will not work). Either use a view model with properties `int ID` and `PagedList<subject>` and use that in the view and the POST method, or add the student ID as a route parameter, and add an additional `int ID` parameter to your method

Comment: And really you should not be generating all those hidden inputs (just degrading performance and opening yourself to overposting attacks). Just include the `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].id)` and the checkbox

Comment: Ohh alright, I am currently trying your solution. I will let you know how did it went, thank you in advance.

Comment: Let me know if your having problems and I'll add an answer.

Comment: Alright im done refactoring everything since i was originally using `student` for post. Do you have any idea why my navigation looks like that? this is my code `@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", "Enrollment", new { page, id = Request.QueryString["id"] }))` ( i will have to fix it for state so it's incomplete )

Comment: That's a css issue. Have you included the relevant css file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model is the view is `@model PagedList<subject>` which means the parameter in the must be

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(IEnumerable<subject> model)
```

If you also need the student `ID` property, then include an additional parameter

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(IEnumerable<subject> model, int ID)
```

Since you GET method has a parameter `int ID` and assuming your using the default routing then the ID will be added to the forms `action` attribute i.e. it will render `action="/Enrollment/Test/2"` assuming the value of the ID is `2`. If not, you can add this as a route parameter

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Enrollment", new { ID = ViewBag.id }))
```

Alternatively you can use a view model

```
public class StudentVM
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public PagedList<student> Students { get; set; }
}
```

and in the GET method

```
public ActionResult Index(int? page, int id=0)
{
  EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();
  student st = emp.students.Single(x=>x.id ==id);
  StudentVM model = new StudentVM()
  {
    ID = id,
    Students = st.subjSel.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 4)
  };
  return View(model);
}
```

and base you view on the view model and post it back to `public ActionResult Test(StudentVM model)`

Comment: Off topic question, do you think it's possible to preserve the state of the checkboxes(which should be included also if i pass them to my post even if they are not shown ex. I check something from page 1 then moved on) that is the next phase that i am working at. I have a feeling that i need to rework on my model since my model has `list` and not `PageList`. I just converted them

Comment: Not entirely sure what your asking. The values of `isSelected` will be posted back. If you mean you check some on one page then go to the next page, then you will need to persist the values somewhere (eg to Session)

Comment: Hmm yeah that's what i meant. Persisting the values. I have thought of adding this to my postback if the user clicked next after checking something. `public ActionResult Index(int? page,IEnumerable<subject> st, int id=0)` . Any tips where to start after so i will be a bit guided instead of blindlessly attempt?

Comment: Not sure of the best way to handle this (I don't use `PagedList`), but you could handle the `.click()` event of your page buttons and get the ID's associated with the checked checkboxes and either post then using ajax or store then on the client (if you store them on the client, you would also need to handle the forms submit event to add the values to the posted form values)

Comment: So ajax is really needed for that scenario?  (i am still not on ajax part so if that is the case then i will pass for now). Can you link me to any tutorials that uses Ajax pagelist? i have been looking for one lately but there's too much and i don't know the good ones.

Comment: I'll think about it a bit more and let you know later.

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta, Could not find any good solution to this. `PagedList` is not intended for editing data. The workaround would be to handle the paging buttons, get all the ID's associated with the checked checkboxes and post them to a controller method which saves them.

Answer (score 1):

To get your list of `subject` back, you should apply a suitable prefix to it. Since the name of property of `Student` that contains `List<subject>` is `subjSel` and you want to get values in your action in a `Student` object, so you should set prefix like this, before `for` statement:

```
@{ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "subjSel";}
```

So fileds of model will be rendered with names like `subjSel[0].fieldname`.

Then in your post action you will receive subjects in `subjSel` property of `st`.

**Additional Resource:**

- [Model Binding to a List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/)

**For your extra question:**

Check if your rendered code has suitable style and your style tags related to paging has been rendered in page.

Comment: As I see in your code, I think this is the only change

Comment: Weird, it's being rendered like `subjSel.[0].subj`

Comment: subjSel[0].fieldname is Completely true, and will solve your problem with model binding. (If you use `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].fieldname )`)

Comment: `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` that's the exception that i get when i try to bind after inserting your code. Normally it should be something like `subjSel[0].subj` without the dot.  `<input id="subjSel__0__subj" name="subjSel.[0].subj" type="hidden" value="COMPRO1" />` that's how it looks like from the solution that you provided.

Comment: 1-When you receive this exception? 2-does your paged list class have a parameterless constructor? 3-Version of MVC?

Comment: Alright i fixed it(sadly this wasn't the solution) but thank you for your help as i have learned something new as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89581/discussion-between-reza-aghaei-and-carlos-miguel-colanta).